# Math accents and Greek letters in glossary name (equation description)

Tags: equations, glossaries, description

I have many equations, where I need to use special characters `\dot` `\bar` and Greek letters like `\tau`. In the equation everything works nice but when I try to write the description `\mathgloss` I receive an error:

`Missing \endcsname inserted \mathgloss{$\dot{b}$}{bbb}{BBB}`

Below you can find my code,where I tried using `$  $` and `\ensuremath{ }`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[3]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2},symbol={#3}}%
  \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
   \item[\gls{#1}]#2 (\textbf{#3})%
  \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a = \dot{b} *c(\tau)
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{$\dot{b}$}{bbb}{BBB}
\mathgloss{ensuremath{c(\tau)}}{ccc}{CCC}

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have active characters in the glossary label. You'll need an extra parameter to provide a label:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[4]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#2},description={#3},symbol={#4}}%
  \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
   \item[\gls{#1}]#3 (\textbf{#4})%
  \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a = \dot{b} *c(\tau)
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{dotb}{$\dot{b}$}{bbb}{BBB}
\mathgloss{ctau}{$c(\tau)$}{ccc}{CCC}

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]