# Glossary entry not printing when name has accented letters using fontspec Old Standard

Tags: glossaries, accents

Related questions are [Math accents and Greek letters in glossary name (equation description)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160061/math-accents-and-greek-letters-in-glossary-name-equation-description) and [Cannot compile glossary entry containing accented character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605518/cannot-compile-glossary-entry-containing-accented-character)

In both cases, the problem was with the label which has to be ASCII printable. But in my case, glossary entry is referenced properly, but not printed in the actual glossary section. The name of the glossary contains an accented letter. If I change the accented letter "{o} to $\ddot{o}$, the entry is printed correctly. Here is a MNWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[toc,nopostdot,nonumberlist,style=long,automake,acronym,section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}

\usepackage{mathspec}

\setallmainfonts{Old Standard}
\subfile{glossary.tex}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \gls{erdos}, \gls{mobius}
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

glossary.tex is

```
\documentclass[]{subfile}

\begin{document}
    \newglossaryentry{mobius}{name=M\"{o}bius function,description={$\mu(n)$ is a very important function in number theory.}}
    \newglossaryentry{erdos}{name={Erd\H{o}s},description={He is Erd\H{o}s}}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like [image]

But if I change it to

```
\documentclass[]{subfile}

\begin{document}
    \newglossaryentry{mobius}{name=M$\ddot{o}$bius function,description={$\mu(n)$ is a very important function in number theory.}}
    \newglossaryentry{erdos}{name={Erd\H{o}s},description={He is Erd\H{o}s}}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this: [image]

However, as expected, the o is slanted since it is in math mode

Comment: no problems here on a current texlive 2021. Did you try to simply type Möbius?

Comment: yes ö works. ö is not available on my keyboard but I guess that's a good workaround. but it's really weird that \H{o} works but \"{o} does not print

Comment: ö is available for input as ^^^^ notation or `\symbol` command, `ö = ^^^^00f6 or \symbol{246}` if you are using a Unicode font that has that glyph.